# How to play video from google drive using javascript?

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api

How to play video from google drive using javascript?

It does not work, how can I do that?

http://fiddle.jshell.net/gt4otyfk/1/

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        var video = $("#video").get(0);
        video.controls = true;
        $("#play").click(function() {
            video.play();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google provides some GET-params like `export` and `id` with google-drive:

```
?export=download&id=YOUR_LONG_VIDEO_ID
```

to give you the ability to insert an uploaded video into a HTML5-video-tag.

This should work:

```js
$("#play").click(function() {
   $("#video")[0].play();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="play" style="margin-top: 300px;">Play</button>

<video id="video" width="320" height="240" controls>
   <source src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=0B8-qLYDzDfCyRF9vOE9sWmx5YjA" type='video/mp4'>
   Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

Just press "Run code snippet"-button to run this example. Hope this helps.

Comment: it doesn't work anymore, looks like the only way now is to use iframe

Answer (score 0):

Just use the preview link you see on your URL when you open/play your video from your Google Drive:
Be sure to include

**sandbox="allow-same-origin allow-scripts allow-popups allow-forms"**

```
  <body>
       <iframe sandbox="allow-same-origin allow-scripts allow-popups allow-forms" width="560" height="315" src="https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bzgk4zccNwI7QkNZRnpBdExHOUk/preview?autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>​
  </body>
```

Got it working:

[image]

Comment: It's working on my end. hence the screenshot. what browser are you using?

Comment: can you send screenshot, what are you seeing? try replacing my video link with your own video link from Drive

Comment: For me ,video not play when press play button.

Comment: Dont press play button.press the video

Comment: I want to play video when press play button ,

Comment: But is it playing when you click the video?