# how to use javascript to play google drive video?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video, google-drive-api

I saw a question like mine on this page: [How to play video from google drive using javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43214124/how-to-play-video-from-google-drive-using-javascript)

However, I have a question. For some reason, this answer from that question:

Google provides some GET-params like `export` and `id` with google-drive:

```
?export=download&id=YOUR_LONG_VIDEO_ID
```

to give you the ability to insert an uploaded video into a HTML5-video-tag.

This should work:

```js
$("#play").click(function() {
   $("#video")[0].play();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="play" style="margin-top: 300px;">Play</button>

<video id="video" width="320" height="240" controls>
   <source src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=0B8-qLYDzDfCyRF9vOE9sWmx5YjA" type='video/mp4'>
   Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

Works well when I test it out on the w3schools tryit:
https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_eff_show_hide

I switched that code for my code, I just use it as my practice area.

But when I place my own video in with the same formula, just switching the original google drive video with my own, my video controls are greyed out and clearly can not play the video. My original video is uploaded on my google photos, put in a named folder on my google drive, where both folder and video are open to anyone with the link access.

I don't understand why the original video works fine, and mine doesn't. It's frustrating because I know using this way of putting a google drive video into the video tag allows me to use my custom controls to control the video. But something is going on with my video for some reason.

Here is my code with the original one, you'll see it's the same.

```js
$("#play").click(function() {
   $("#video")[0].play();
});

$("#play2").click(function() {
   $("#video2")[0].play();
});
```

```html
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<button id="play" style="margin-top: 300px;">Play</button>
<video id="video" width="320" height="240" controls>
   <source src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=0B8-qLYDzDfCyRF9vOE9sWmx5YjA" type='video/mp4'>
   Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
<br>
<br>
<button id="play2" style="margin-top: 300px;">Play</button>
<video id="video2" width="320" height="240" controls>
   <source src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1hLjl0TDEOnPrgXhFxAVNL5fM_qLtCgB9lA" type='video/mp4'>
   Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

Lots of help will be GREAT!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to me, there is permission problem with your drive video.Because I have tried to hit on your link I am getting error of permission. But previous drive's video((working fine)) easily accessible.

Comment: Yes! It was! Thank you so much. Because I had changed the link to the download one, I had to make it so viewers can download the video. That's why it wasn't working. So when I gave permission, the video worked! Thanks so much!!!

Answer (score 0):

Go to your video in Google Drive.
Right-click and select get shareable links, then change your sharing setting to 'On - Public on the Web'.

[Refer Image for sharing setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3whJC.jpg)

Comment: It ended up not being that, but thanks anyway! It was a permission problem of viewers being able to download or not. I can still have the link as just anyone with the link can view.