# iFrame video not playing on iPhone (Safari)

Tags: html, ios, css, iframe, safari

I have a video page on my website which is linked to my google drive via the following code:

I am using google drive instead of YouTube, due to copyright issues with music.

The video links work fine on desktop (even though I don't like the idea of clicking twice on file). It used to work on mobile but doesn't now. Is there a way around this to work on mobile please?

Code:

`<iframe style="align src="https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YjBhWH4scLK4B-yR_fUXeJehUmtlFoFJ/preview" width="400" height="300" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe>`

Thanks
Bini

Comment: Can you give us code

Comment: Thanks for your reply, this is the code for one of the videos:

<iframe style="align src="https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YjBhWH4scLK4B-yR_fUXeJehUmtlFoFJ/preview" width="400" height="300" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe>

do you need any more info?

Comment: I edited your post to include your code :)

Comment: I just used the info from following link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43214124/how-to-play-video-from-google-drive-using-javascript

which worked well within Safar, until I placed my own video ID and it didnt work, which is very strange. 

my ID is 1YjBhWH4scLK4B-yR_fUXeJehUmtlFoFJ, unless I've got it wrong?

Comment: you never closed your `style="align` quotation in the given code. That might be a problem

Comment: Just checked it and still doesn't work.

Comment: The following code works for me, but not when i replace it with my own video ID, any idea on why this might not work?

Comment: $("#play").click(function() {
   $("#video")[0].play();
});

Comment: <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="play" style="margin-top: 300px;">Play</button>

<video id="video" width="320" height="240" controls>
   <source src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=0B8-qLYDzDfCyRF9vOE9sWmx5YjA" type='video/mp4'>
   Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>

Comment: Please edit your post to add you code instead of just commenting it. It's a lot harder to read the comment

Answer (score 0):

Check if the attribute in your iframe are valid and compatible with for the iOS and safari version
you can use: http://validator.w3.org

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Do I use 'Validate by Direct Input' ?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this to play after disabling cross-site tracking prevention under Safari > Preferences > Privacy.

It seems to be related to ITP and cross-site tracking prevention.

Answer (score -1):

Use this method. Replace "videoID" at the end of the url.

```
<video controls>
    <source src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=videoID" type='video/mp4'>
</video>
```

Comment: This allows direct video download, what I think is unwanted due to copyright issues mentioned in question.